# Returning a list from recursive function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns a list of the sizes of squares that can be inside rectangle. First I solved it with a while loop, but now I'm trying to use recursion. So, here is the code:

```
def sqInRect(lng, wdth, list=[]):
    if lng == wdth and not list:
        return None
    if lng == 0 or wdth == 0:
        return list
    elif lng > wdth:
        list.append(wdth)
        return sqInRect(lng-wdth, wdth)
    else:
        list.append(lng)
        return sqInRect(lng, wdth-lng)
```

The shell gives me correct values, but I'm solving this task on a certain website. That's what I get. How can I avoid it?

> [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1] should equal [3, 2, 1, 1]
>
> [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2] should equal [14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2]
>
> [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2] should equal [14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2]
>
> [3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 14, 6, 6, 2, 2, 2, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 16] should equal [32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 16, 16]

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the only problem in your code, but take a look at ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](//stackoverflow.com/q/1132941)

Comment: I recommend to not name variables after keywords. You named an argument `list` which is a built-in function.